# Update a table based on a temporary table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to update a column of a table(national_id from Personal_info) based on a value of a temporary table(nationalid from Tmp_Tbl).

Below Two tables having a pk/fk relation with each other using cid,user_id.

**Users(cid,user_name)**

**Personal_info(user_id,national_id)**

Temporary table also have a relation to Users table using user_name which is unique.

**Tmp_Tbl(user_name,nationalid)**

As it is oracle , i don't want to use of update join and also not merge syntax as i have the solution already.i am looking for a simple update query to use.

Comment: Unfortunately but join is the answer that i can see which you already have!

Comment: Oracle does not support joins in the UPDATE statements

Comment: @Peter . . . Oracle supports joins in subqueries and it supports subqueries in the `UPDATE`.  It doesn't support `UPDATE` *using* `JOIN`; there is a subtle difference.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you can do this using subqueries, but you need to be careful.  You need a similar subquery in the `set` and the `where`:

```
UPDATE Personal p
   SET national_id = (SELECT t.nationalid
                      FROM tmp_tbl t JOIN
                           users u
                           ON t.user_name = u.user_name
                      WHERE u.cid = p.user_id
                     )
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM tmp_tbl t JOIN
                      users u
                      ON t.user_name = u.user_name
                 WHERE u.cid = p.user_id
                );
```

If you leave out the `WHERE` clause, you will erase the `national_id` of users that are not in the temp table.

This assumes that you just want to update values for existing users.  If you want to both add new users and insert values, then the code is more complicated.

Comment: There is no user_id in tmp_tbl,that is the main point...ON t.user_id = u.cid

Comment: @Peter . . . I answered before coffee.  There were several mistakes.